# Find all lines containing string, then add value at the end

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm trying to edit some big file and i need to add some symbols at the end of each line containing string. Example:

```
subject aaa tested
subject bbb tested
subject ccc tested
```

If there's 'subject bbb' in line id like to add 'ok' at the end.

```
subject aaa tested
subject bbb tested ok
subject ccc tested
```

So far I'm using Notepad++ and I'm here:

```
FIND: ^.*(subject bbb).*$
REPLACE: \1 ok
```

Output:

```
subject bbb ok
```

Any tips?

Comment: capture all the line.

Comment: [This is how](https://regex101.com/r/nJ1wV6/1)

Comment: Thank works stribizhev  ;-). Thank You!

Comment: Posted a lighter version.

Answer (score 0):

Change your regex to `^.*(subject bbb.*)$`

Answer (score 0):

You need to match the whole line and then replace with `$& ok`:

```
^.*subject bbb.*$
```

No capturing group is necessary since you replace the whole match value (`$&` is a back-reference to the whole matched text).

Also, if you need to match `bbb` or `subject` as a whole word, you need to use word boundary `\b`:

```
^.*\bsubject bbb\b.*$
```

See screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Thank You a lot for great explanation stribizhev! Can You refer any good sites to learn some regex basics?

Comment: Regex basics are covered at [regular-expressions.info](http://regular-expressions.info) and to test your regexps, you can use [regex101.com](http://regex101.com). Also, check the [What does this regex mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean) SO post.